# Вставить одну матрицу в другую

Tags: python, numpy

Первая матрица - это пустое изображение

```
blank_img=np.zeros(shape=[int(new_x), int(new_y)])
print(blank_img.shape)
(2074, 1570)
```

Вторая матрица -это одноканальное изображение

```
im_first= cv2.imread('1.tif',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
(1280, 960)
```

Как поместить вторую матрицу в первую? Т.е. первое изображение - это подложка для остальных изображений
Для примера

```
A=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

B=[[2, 3, 4]
  [5, 6, 7]
  [8, 9, 3]]
```

Желаемый результат

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0]
 [0, 0, 5, 6, 7, 0]
 [0, 0, 8, 9, 3, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Что значит поместить матрицу в матрицу? Наложить их? Тогда нужно знать правила наложения. Это можно сделать множеством способов.

Comment: Приведите в вопросе маленькие примеры входных данных (скажем размерностей 8х6 и 5х4) и результат, который вы хотите получить. Кроме этого следует объяснить правила наложения.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать через срезы, используя ваш пример:

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

B=np.array([[2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7],
  [8, 9, 3]])

A[1:4,2:5] = B # со строки с индексом 1 (нумерация с 0) и с колонки 2 и до указанных строки и колонки
A
```

Вывод:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0],
       [0, 0, 5, 6, 7, 0],
       [0, 0, 8, 9, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Хотелось бы по индексам

Comment: А это и есть индексы - по строке и по колонке. Нумерация с нуля. Откуда и докуда.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
>>> A = np.ones((3,3)) # Создаем просто матрицу из единиц
>>> np.pad(A, (1,2))  # Добавляем обрамление нулями по выбранным измерениям.
>>> array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
          [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
          [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: Хорошо, но ничего непонятно же

Comment: Я сделал поведение аналогичное вашему, из вопроса не понятно, что и как :)

Comment: Да это я понял, но тут принято пояснять, что вы сделали хотя бы кратко. Код без объяснений тут не любят )